# How can I convert a string to Unicode in swift?

Tags: swift, unicode, converters

I need convert String to Unicode,like this:
           let str = "哈哈123abc" 
Because I send data is limited, so I need the most saving way，what should i do

Comment: What String representation are you starting with? What is the String representation that you want to convert to? Take a look at the [Strings and Characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID293) documentation and see if it helps to improve your question.

Comment: I am used to BLE peripheral. The name, will be limited to 18 byte, including Chinese characters, Numbers and characters, Chinese characters 3 byte, because unicode is a 2 byte, so need to string converted to unicode

Comment: What encoding does the [Chinese characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_encoding) have? Do you want to end up with UTF-8?

Comment: I need to convert any character to 2 byte

Answer (score 17):

This way you can convert String to Unicode in swift3

```
var str : String = "哈哈123abc"

//String to Unicode
var dataenc = str.data(using: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII)
var encodevalue = String(data: dataenc!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

//Unicode to String
var datadec  = encodevalue?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
var decodevalue = String(data: datadec!, encoding: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII)
```

Comment: oh,thanks,but,how convert  Unicode to String in swift3?

Comment: How do we do this for attributed string?

Comment: encode value gives two slash and it's not working, please check your answer again